# if last li then set click event on it

Tags: javascript, xslt

this is my xslt file:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <li onclick="final()">
      <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]" />
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*/*">
    <ul>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" 
                            mode="item" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is my xml file:-

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="a.xsl"?> 
<root>
  <child_1 entity_id = "1" value="Game" parent_id="0">
    <child_2 entity_id="2" value="Activities" parent_id="1">
      <child_3 entity_id="3" value="Physical1" parent_id="2">
        <child_6 entity_id="6" value="Cricket" parent_id="3">
          <child_7 entity_id="7" value="One Day" parent_id="6"/>
        </child_6>
      </child_3>
      <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Test1" parent_id="1">
        <child_8 entity_id="8" value="Test At Abc" parent_id="4"/>
      </child_4>
      <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Test2" parent_id="1">
        <child_9 entity_id="9" value="Test At Xyz" parent_id="5"/>
      </child_5>
    </child_2>
   <child_10 entity_id="10" value="Region" parent_id="1">
      <child_11 entity_id="11" value="ABC" parent_id="10">
        <child_12 entity_id="12" value="XYZ" parent_id="11">
          <child_13 entity_id="13" value="ABC123" parent_id="12"/>
        </child_12>
      </child_11>
  </child_10>
</child_1>
</root>
```

i am try to create ul li from the xml file.
here i am set every `li` click event using `onclick` function.
but now i want to only last `li` click event not every `li`.
something like:-

- Activities

  - Physical

    - Cricket

      - One Day

now i want to in last `Li`

```
<li onclick ="final()">OneDay</li>
```

Comment: You should check position() of li element to get last() li and put your attribute

Comment: @NavinRawat i am also fine  `<xsl:if test="position()=last()">` but where i put li to check in side position(li)?

Comment: share your input XML with us

Comment: @NavinRawat check it my edited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your XSLT with the required one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::node()/child::*">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <li onclick="final()">
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*/*">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To get output:

```
<ul>
   <li>Physical1
      <ul>

         <li>Cricket
            <ul>

               <li onclick="final()">One Day</li>

            </ul>
         </li>

      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>ABC
      <ul>

         <li>XYZ
            <ul>

               <li onclick="final()">ABC123</li>

            </ul>
         </li>

      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```